# MySQL Stored Procedure, read from one table and insert to other

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this following code in PHP and I want to convert this into MySQL stored procedure. I do not want to check on duplication error at db level error code due to the requirement of the application, it has to be done the same way as is done in PHP.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT zip__ID FROM zip WHERE zip_code='" . $zip . "' ";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0) {
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO zips SET zip_code='" . ($zip) . "'";
    mysql_query($sql3);
    $newZip = mysql_insert_id();
} else {
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    $newZip = $row2['zip_id'];
}
```

//Update: May 6, 2015.
I have total 6 tables.

Table 1 contains fields like zip, city, state, country. This is in varchar format.
|ID|ZIP|CITY|STATE|COUNTRY|
|1|33430|Fort Lauderdale|FL|USA

There are four more tables that are:
Table 2: zips (id,zip_code)
Table 3: cities (id,city_name)
Table 4: state (id,state_name)
Table 5: countries (id,country_name)

I want to insert the date from table 1 into table 6, which is the replica of table 1. The only difference is that in Table 6, I want to insert IDs of the data in table 1. Hence, for every insertion to be made in Table 6, I have to run a query in the 4 tables (2,3,4 and 5). For instance, if the zip code in Table 1 is 33430 and it does not exist in Table 2, first I need to insert it, get its ID and then insert in Table 6.

I have to do the same for all fields in Table 1.

So if I do it in PHP, what I will do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result){
    $zip = $row['zip'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $state = $row['state'];
    $country = $row['country'];

    //Process zip code
    $sql2 = "SELECT zip_id FROM zips WHERE zip_code='" . $zip . "' ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0) {
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO zips SET zip_code='" . ($zip) . "'";
        mysql_query($sql3);
        $newZip = mysql_insert_id();
    } else {
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        $newZip = $row2['zip_id'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($result2);

    //Process city
    $sql2 = "SELECT city_id FROM cities WHERE city_name='" . $city . "' ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0) {
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO cities SET city_name='" . ($city) . "'";
        mysql_query($sql3);
        $newCity = mysql_insert_id();
    } else {
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        $newCity = $row2['city_id'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($result2);

    //process other two tables......

}mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: You can do it in one sql statement with a `IF EXISTS`. Do you `SET` in MySQL? An Insert statement systax is normally `INSERT TABLE (<columns>) VALUES (<values>)` or `INSERT TABLE SELECT <VALUES>`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what is required. It has to be done the way it has been mentioned.

I have to select values from one table, then see if the exist is multiple tables then insert where required.

Comment: Ok, But what is the problem then. what you have, except for the syntax of the insert statement, it seems that you will insert a values in your table if the is no results.

Comment: OK, let me explain you the entire scenario. The code above is just a portion of what I want to build. In actual, below is what I want.

There are not just 2 tables involved, there are more tables involved. I have to read from one table from different fields and get its ID from its corresponding table either after insertion or by selecting if it is already there. Each field of the first table refers to another master table.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem, because all you need to do is what you just explained. Don't you know how to do it? Are you new to this? Do you have a basic understanding on how to do this?

Comment: Yes, I can write procedures but this is a complex one. I am updating the main post with more details.

Comment: I have updated the requirement with more details.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no MySQL expert either, but this is what I could find. You have to check out the syntax though. But I want to stress this. I Googled 2 sources, and I typed this out for you. If I could do it, I'm sure you could've done it as well.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTable6()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE i, a, b, c, d INT;
DECLARE va, vb, vc, vd CHAR(<yourmax>);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, zip, city, state, country FROM table1;

OPEN cur1;
read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cut1 into i, va, vb, vc, vd;
  IF done THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
  END IF;

  --REPEAT THIS FOR ALL 4 TABLES
  IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM Table2 WHERE zip_code=va) THEN
    BEGIN
      SELECT a = TableID FROM Table2 WHERE zip_code=va;
    END;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Table2 (zip_code) VALUES(va);
      SELECT a = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END;
  END IF;

  --CHECK DETAILS IN TABLE6
  IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM Table6 WHERE id=i) THEN
    BEGIN
      UPDATE TABLE6 set zip_id = a, city_id = b, state_id = c, country_id = d where id = i
    END;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Table6 (zip_id, city_id, state_id, country_id ) VALUES(a, b, c, d);
    END;
  END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

My source where https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: Thank you, but I want to write a stored procedure for this. In PHP, all is being done without any issue.

Comment: Ahhh.. Now that does sound better. Sorry, I must have missed one of the statements in your question. Do you want to call the proc for every records, or do you want to handle the record looping in php, and execute the proc once for every record

Comment: Jaques, thanks for your constant follow-up. I need one procedure to handle it all.

Comment: Will the proc that I gave to you in the answer help?